# How can I combine a field from an array into another array of the same length?

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript arrays:

```
var ar1 = [ 
          {"x":1,"y":"xxxxx"},
          {"x":3,"y":"yyyyy"}
        ];


var ar2 = [ 
          {"a":1,"b":"bbbbb"},
          {"a":3,"b":"bbbbb"}
        ];
```

How can I use a forEach a function to take the "b" field of the second array `ar2` and add it to the `ar1` array so that the `ar1` array now has three fields. Note that these arrays are always the same length.

}

Comment: I would start with some loops.

Comment: Have you tried looping over both arrays at the same time?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do it with a forEach and a function but I am not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Use the second parameter to the callback function which provides the index you're at to access the other array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with parallel arrays, one needs to iterate over the indexes.

```
for (i=0; i<ar1.length; ++i) {
   ar1[i].b = ar2[i].b;
}
```

`forEach` does provide the index, so we can use that too.

```
ar1.forEach(function(element, index, array){
   element.b = ar2[index].b;
});
```